# Factoring a 5 term polynomial

Tags: polynomials, factoring

I am struggling to factor $n^4 + 4n^3 + 8n^2 + 8n +4$.

I have tried grouping the terms a couple of times, but got nowhere. What am I missing?

Comment: In this case, it is a sum of two squares, $n^4+4n^3+4n^2$ and $4n^2+8n+4$.  That can be factored as $(A+iB)(A-iB)$, with both factors quadratics.  Maybe you can solve the quadratics, get four complex linear factors, and combine them back into two real quadratics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I would try are degree one factors, which by the [Rational Roots Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) must have the form $n + d$ where $d$ is an integer divisor of $4$.

Once these possibilities are exhausted, the only factors left to check are quadratic ones:

$$ n^4 + 4n^3 + 8n^2 + 8n + 4 = (n^2 + an + b)(n^2 + cn + d) $$

where $a,b,c,d$ are integers with the restrictions implied by collecting like powers of $n$.  For example, $bd = 4$.  There are not many of these to check.

This particular polynomial yields to a trick for finding square-free factors.  One takes the derivative of the polynomial $4n^3 + 12n^2 + 16n + 8$, and computes the greatest common divisor of the derivative with the original:

$$ 4n^3 + 12n^2 + 16n + 8 = 4(n^3 + 3n^2 + 4n + 2) = 4(n+1)(n^2 + 2n + 2) $$

One way or the other, one finds the original polynomial factors as $(n^2 + 2n + 2)^2$.

Comment: Think I get it. Is there anywhere I could get more information on Rational Roots Theorem? Thanks.

Comment: Sure, the Wikipedia article is pretty good.  You may know this by another name as it will be covered in a basic Algebra II class.  I'll add a link to the Answer.

Comment: Wouldn't it be of form $n\pm d$?

Answer (score 3):

This is an approach based on pattern recognition.

Recall the Pascal's triangle
$$1\\
1 \quad 1\\
1 \quad 2 \quad 1\\
1 \quad 3 \quad 3 \quad 1\\
1 \quad 4 \quad 6 \quad 4 \quad 1$$
The coefficients of the polynomial at hand are
$$1 \quad 4 \quad 8 \quad 8 \quad 4$$ 
They look "close" to $5^{th}$ row of above triangle.
This suggest us to rewrite our polynomial as a sum $(n+1)^4$ plus some small pieces:

$$n^4 + 4n^3 + 8n^2 + 8n + 4 =  (n+1)^4 + 2n^2 + 4n + 3$$

The coefficient of the small piece
$$2\quad 4 \quad 3$$
now looks like twice the $3^{rd}$ row of above triangle. This suggest us to
rewrite the small piece as a sum of $2(n+1)^2$ plus an even smaller piece.

$$2n^2 + 4n + 3 = 2(n+1)^2 + 1$$

Combine these, we get something that one can complete the square. Complete the square and we are basically done!

$$n^4 + 4n^3 + 8n^2 + 8n + 4 = (n+1)^4 + 2(n+1)^2 + 1\\
= ((n+1)^2 + 1)^2 = (n^2 + 2n + 2)^2
$$

Comment: That's a pretty cool way of doing it.